# DispatcherUnhandledException doesn't work as expected

Tags: c#, wpf

In my application (`c#`, `wpf`, `VS2015`) I try to process `DispatcherUnhandledException` error handling in the following manner:

```
private void App_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
  MessageBox.Show("An unhandled exception just occurred: " + e.Exception.Message, 
        "Exception Sample", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
  e.Handled = true;
  Environment.Exit(-1);
}
```

When I start w/o IDE the application quits w/o any dialog message. When starting with IDE get `"Exception thrown: 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' in PresentationFramework.dll"`. Starting dialog using `Dispatcher` doesn't change anything.

Comment: my guess is that framework cannot parse some part of xaml (XamlParseException) and therefore cannot even create startup window. double check your markup. (http://geekswithblogs.net/lbugnion/archive/2007/03/14/108728.aspx)

Comment: @Ash the application works OK. I've just added a wrong code to generate error and check error processing. So it shows startup window and works fine util I try to execute bad code.